# Custom UIView in UITableViewCell Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uitableview

I am drawing a custom UIView in every table view cell like so:

```
    _checkboxView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 28.5, cell.frame.size.height - 33.5, 25, 25)] autorelease];
    _checkboxView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _checkboxView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;
    _checkboxView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    _checkboxView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    [cell addSubview:_checkboxView];
    [cell bringSubviewToFront:_checkboxView];
```

This works perfectly, but when the phone is switched to landscape mode, the checkbox is in the wrong place, and goes near the middle of the table view cell. I need it to stay anchored to the right side of the cell using the constraints I made for portrait mode. Naturally, I would just go to  the method:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

But how do I make sure that I am able to properly anchor the view for every UITableViewCell? I can't use interface builder (and thus Auto Layout) because the entire thing is built programatically. How would I get a handle of the specific cell it's looking at in this method?

Comment: Try `_checkboxView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;`

Comment: WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 2):

try to set the `autoresizingMask` for that view like...

```
[_checkboxView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

ENJOY CODING.........

Comment: your answer is correct, but someone already answered this question with a comment. thank you though!